# How can I check a parameter matches a value in my enum in C#?

Tags: c#

I have this enum:

```
public enum ContentKey {
    Menu = 0,
    Article = 1,
    FavoritesList = 2
};
```

This action method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string pk, string rk, int row = 0) {
    try {
        var content = _contentService.Get(pk, rk);
```

The following class `Content` which is based on the `TableServiceEntity`. Note that `TableServiceEntity` is common to all my data classes.

```
public class Content : TableServiceEntity 
{

public abstract class TableServiceEntity
{
    protected TableServiceEntity();
    protected TableServiceEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey);
    public virtual string PartitionKey { get; set; }
```

Is there a way I can check the value of `pk` matches one of the enum values? What I am not sure about is how I can check this. I assume I need to have the check in the `Content` class but I am not sure how to override the `virtual string` and throw an exception when there's no match.

**Update**: If possible I would like to do this in the Content class get set but I am not sure how to add a get set to this class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Enum.IsDefined`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to see if a `string` matches an Enum value:

```
public enum ContentKey
{
    Menu = 0,
    Article = 1,
    FavoritesList = 2
}

static bool Check(string pk)
{
    return Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ContentKey), pk);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Check("Menu"));
    Console.WriteLine(Check("Foo"));
}
```

You can also define a setter that does not set the backing field unless the new `value` is defined the enum:

```
class Foo
{
    private string pk;

    public string PK
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pk;
        }
        set
        {
            if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ContentKey), value))
            {
                this.pk = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a non-automatic property where you define the backing field yourself. The new value is accessible via the `value` keyword.

Comment: Is there a way I could put this inside a get set of the Content Class. I am sorry I just updated the question to ask about this. It was what I was hoping to do.

Comment: Thanks Mudu, My TableServiceEntity uses public virtual string PartitionKey as the property. Will it be okay if I change what you did to use PartitionKey instead of pk ?

Comment: Yes, of course. `PK` or `PartitionKey` is just the name. Should be fine to make it `virtual` to if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enum.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx):

```
ContentKey key = (ContentKey) Enum.Parse(typeof(ContentKey), pk);
```

It will throw an [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) if `pk` does not match any named constant defined in `ContentKey`.

Comment: Do you think it would be best if I could code this into a get / set of the Content Class. This is what I was really wanting to do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a property setter that takes a string? I don't think you actually have to. Did you try relying on the model binder and having your action method take a `ContentKey` instead of a string?

Comment: That's a good idea but I think if I could add it to the class then it would just be done in the one place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(ContentKey),pk))
{
   //Do your work;
}
```